# GLSL shaders, gl_ModelViewMatrix not correct?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

So I was trying to make a shader that changed the color of my crystal a little bit over time, and it all went fine until i noticed that it didn't get darker the further away it went from the light source ( default opengl lights for now! ). So I tried to tone down the color values by the distance away from the light it was but that didn't work. Later on i discovered ( by setting the color to red if the x position of the vertex in world coordinates was greater than a certain value ), that the vertex.x value was around 0. Even though it should be about 87.0.

```
void main()
{
    vec3 vertexPosition = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * vertexPos);
    vec3 surfaceNormal = (gl_NormalMatrix * normals).xyz;
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vertexPosition);
    float diffuseLI = max(0.0, dot(surfaceNormal, lightDirection));

    vec4 texture = texture2D(textureSample, gl_TexCoord[0]);
    if(vertexPosition.x > 0)gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    /*And so on....*/
}
```

As far as I know gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex should give the world coordinates of the vertex. Am I just stupid or what?
( I also tried to do the same if statement with the light position which was correct! )

Comment: `gl_ModelViewMatrix` will transform to eye space. Fixed function GL never had a "world space".

Comment: @derhass How would i go about getting it to world coordinates?

Comment: You would neet to split apart `gl_ModelView` into a `view` (for world-to-eye) and a `model` (for object-to-world) part. There are no builtin matrices for that. However, what do you need world space for? Eye space will be fine, usually.

Comment: @derhass Okay thanks I figured it out. By passing my transformation in as a uniform matrix and multipling it by that instead thanks!